# How to compute weights using design matrix for 2D training data?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I want to implement linear regression on a data set with 2 features (2D) with 5D space (basis or mapping function dimensions).

If I use the simplest form of basis function which is phi(x)=x, what are 5 basis functions that can map a point in 2D space to 5D space?

In general, how different dimensions of x are used in basis functions to map from 2D space to 5D space? As you know there are different basis functions: Gaussian, sigmoidal

Thanks.